# Highlight and label anything in LaTex article

Tags: labels, highlighting, todonotes, soul

I'm looking for a package that highlights and labels anything I wrap with it. So that I can then create a list of those highlights according to the label.
I was thinking of something like the todonotes package command `\listoftodos` and also the possibility of an option like the todonotes package option: `disable`.

Any suggestions?

P.S.
I’ve seen `soul` package but it has problems with both linebreaks and `\cite` command.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [`lua-ul`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-ul). For the list, it depends a lot on what kinds of things you want to highlight and how it should be displayed. Maybe a simple index is enough?

Comment: Yes, a simple index is enough. However, I have two problems with LuaLatex: I can't set it up in Aquamacs (the editor I use) and it gives me problems compiling my document with TeXShop anyway.

Comment: I don't have know that editor or own a Mac, but any reasonable editor should allow switching to LuaLaTeX fairly easily. Typically, you only need to change your font setup in order to make the switch. If you need help with that, you can find some useful answers on this site. If you do not want to use LuaLaTeX, you will have to live with the shortcomings of the different approaches available in pdfLaTeX.